# Unity3D Void Start not working as it should

Tags: unity-game-engine

http://prntscr.com/aow9qf What is wrong here? I have been examining everything for 2 hours now, but can't see why the buttons don't get set to false at the start while they are doing their job fine in the other voids.

Comment: Have you tried using `Debug.Log()` to identify whether variables are what you expect them to be, or that the code in question is being run at all? Additionally, please try to include relevant code as text in your actual question, and not linked off-site or in an image. (Otherwise...you're going to attract quite a few "Off-topic - must include code in question" close votes/comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it could be because there's no `MolButtons` object in the scene during Start execution: try putting all the stuff you're currently doing in Start in a coroutine, then make it do the stuff with one frame delay (with `return new WaitForEndOfFrame();`)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please PLEASE modify the question to include a bit of code, so that others can solve their problems without an external website that may go down ;)